# Magento2: Can't use OrderCommentSender to send an email

Tags: magento2, email

getting this error

```
    File:   /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php
    Error:  Area code is not set
    Line:   139
    Stack trace:
    #0 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php(126): Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode()
    #1 /chroot/home/html/var/generation/Magento/Theme/Model/View/Design/Proxy.php(103): Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design->getArea()
    #2 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(584): Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design\Proxy->getArea()
    #3 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(608): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->getDesignConfig()
    #4 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php(413): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->setDesignConfig(Array)
    #5 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(257): Magento\Email\Model\Template->setOptions(Array)
    #6 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(267): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->getTemplate()
    #7 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(227): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->prepareMessage()
    #8 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php(66): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->getTransport()
    #9 /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/NotifySender.php(34): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder->send()
    #10 /chroot/home/html/app/code/Bss/OrderDeliveryDate/Model/Plugin/Sales/Order/Email/Sender/OrderCommentSender.php(46): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\NotifySender->checkAndSend(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order), true)
    #11 /chroot/home/html/pub/test.php(203): Bss\OrderDeliveryDate\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender->send(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order), true, '123456+SWOG')
    #12 /chroot/home/html/pub/test.php(355): Data->updateOrder('000001469', '2018-3-15', 'Complete', 'complete', 'yes', '123456', 'SWOG', 'SWOG')
    #13 {main}
```

when running this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncId);
$state =  $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$notificationEmail = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender');
$notificationEmail->send($order, true, "Order Completed!");
```

i can't figure out what i missing, i am setting the area code but it doesn't seem to see that

Comment: Where did you put your code lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

required alot of hoop jumping in the form of the below to be used in addition to just setting the area code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$configLoader = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface');
$objectManager->configure($configLoader->load('frontend'));
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode("frontend");
```